# What exactly happens when awaiting a promise in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

One point that I can’t seem to find anywhere in documentation or related resources is what the procedure is, in regards to the calling function and the event loop, when JS hits the `await` keyword.

Here’s what the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) state:

> The await expression causes async function execution to pause until a Promise is resolved, that is fulfilled or rejected, and to resume execution of the async function after fulfillment. When resumed, the value of the await expression is that of the fulfilled Promise.

That all makes sense, but what really is meant by pause? Does the function immediately return to the caller and then when the promise that’s being awaited resolves, it and the rest of the async method gets added to the microtask queue for handling? I know that `async/await` is syntactic sugar for the Promise API, so I’m assuming that this is sorta what happens, but I want to make sure I’m really understanding the “magic” that happens when an `await` is reached.

From what I’ve read, this seems to be what’s done in C#, but I’m not exactly sure how it translates to JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is exactly as you said, it puts the rest of the function into a micro task, and continues the main function.

Then when the promise resolves, it queues that task so the async part gets executed.

What helps me to understand it is to convert the async/await into promise syntax, and then it gets clear.

For example:

```js
async function doSomthing() {
  someSync();

  const result1 = await someAsync();
  const result2 = await someAsync2();

  return result1 + result2;
}
```

"converts" to:

```js
function doSomthing() {
  someSync();

  return someAsync().then(result1 => {
    return someAsync2().then(result2 => {
      return result1 + result2;
    });
  });
}
```

You can see that `doSomthing` immediately returns the promise.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What do you mean by it “returns the main function”?

Comment: That `doSomthing` in my example return a promise immediately without anything async.

Comment: thank you! Now if instead however you have code executing in the function before the first await, it does not return until the await keyword is hit, right?

Comment: If there is code that is sync before the first `await`, it gets executed before queuing the first async operation

Comment: I've updated my answer, the `someSync` function will be executed before `someAsync`

Comment: @Ry- I don't think "*it puts the rest of the function into a micro task queue*" was meant here. "A microtask queue" is weird, since there is only a single one, and also `await` does not actually put anything into the queue. It's the `then()` mechanism that does that, when the promise settles, not earlier!

Comment: @Bergi: I agree it’s weird, but do you really mean you don’t think it was meant? I’m not sure what else Q could have been, and the wording is in the question.

Comment: @Ry- It might have been a name, like "the task T", then later "queue T"? I'll assume the best… but only felixmosh can tell us.

Answer (score -4):

**await/async means that we execute the code synchronously. It will follow the order of the await function is called within async function. 
for example: It will process the execution line by line like it waits it the response is returned from await and then it proceeds further.**

```
 `function doubleAfter2Seconds(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(x * 2);
      }, 2000);
    });
  }

  async function addAsync(x) {
     console.log("Here I am before first await"); 
    const a = await doubleAfter2Seconds(10);
    console.log("A ouput is ",a);
    const b = await doubleAfter2Seconds(20);
    console.log("B ouput is ",b);
    const c = await doubleAfter2Seconds(30);
    console.log("C ouput is ",c);
    return x + a + b + c;
  }


  addAsync(10).then((sum) => {
    console.log(sum);
  });`
```

The above code will output the result like below:

[image]

*Hope this helps to understand async/await*